# Is $T$ singular or nonsingular for $T(A)=AB - BA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $B$ be a complex $n\times n$ matrix. Prove or disprove: The linear operator $T$ on the space of all $n\times n$ matrices defined by $ T(A) = AB - BA $ is singular.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$T(I)=0$, where $I$ is the identity. So.. the map has a nontrivial kernal.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**. Consider rank-nullity. Does the map have a nontrivial kernel? That is, is there a subspace of matrices that commute with $B$? (In fact, there is a nontrivial subspace of matrices that commute with *every* complex $n\times n$ matrix...)

Answer (score 4):

Well, if $B$ is the zero matrix, this is simple, and if not, what is $T(B)$?